# Android (API 7) - Animation : onAnimationRepeat

Tags: android

I have an issue with my apps : I would like to modify an ImageView when the animation is repeated but the `onAnimationRepeat` function (from the `AnimationListener` class) is not called.

This is a sample to reproduce it:

- Create a new project "test" (Android 2.1, API 7) (I used `com.test.test` for package name)
- Create a folder `anim` inside `res` folder and create `fade_in.xml` with these lines

[image: fade_in.xml]

The activity code:

```
package com.test.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    Button button = null;
    ImageView image = null;

    Animation animation = null;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
        animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {            

            int repeatNumber = 0;

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {Log.i("start", "start");}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {Log.i("end", "end");}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                repeatNumber++;
                Log.i("repeat", String.valueOf(repeatNumber));
                switch(repeatNumber)
                {
                case 1:image.setColorFilter(Color.RED, Mode.MULTIPLY);break;
                case 2:image.setColorFilter(Color.BLUE, Mode.MULTIPLY);break;
                case 3:image.setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW, Mode.MULTIPLY);break;
                default:break;
                }
            }
        });

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {image.startAnimation(animation);}
        });

    }
}
```

And the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The `ImageView` color doesn't change...Can you help me?

Comment: please check the counter variable value maybe it will not reset

Comment: Log.i("repeat", String.valueOf(repeatNumber)); => It never appears in logcat. repeatNumber was created only for sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `AnimationUtils.loadAnimation()` returns an array of Animation.

You have to set the event on the item of this array.

You can declare an AnimationSet

```
AnimationSet animation = null;
```

So after the instruction

```
animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
```

You can write :

```
    for (Animation a : animation.getAnimations())
        a.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                Log.i("repeat", "repeat");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {}
        });
```

This will work.

Comment: animation = (AnimationSet)AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);

I confirm, it works perfectly (I will submit your solution to Ed Lalouche !).

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

For repeat the animation you need to set the repeat mode for animation and number of repeat occurrence.

```
anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);
anim.setRepeatCount(5);
```

Comment: I've tried to use code behind instead of xml file, it doesn't change anything. android:repeatCount="3" works in xml file but the function onAnimationRepeat in the listener is not called.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and read a lot of resources and animation problem answers. Everyone was complaining about the AnimationSet and repeat count problem. So i removed the   Tag from the XML and it worked. OnRepeat and onEnd both are getting called now.